# Differentiating a function but not arriving at correct answer?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have a function $f(x)=(8x^2+7)^3(x^3-7)^4$

I have differentiated it using the chain rule and arrived at:

$3(8x^2+7)^2 \cdot 16x \cdot 4(x^3-7)^3 \cdot 3x^2$ And apparently this is wrong?

What am I missing here?

Comment: You'd have to use the product rule at some point as well, and it doesn't look like you've applied it correctly.

Comment: Oh, of course. I am so stupid.

Comment: Happens to all of us!

Comment: I now get an answer of $3(8t^2+7)^2\cdot16t\cdot(t^3-7)^4+(8t^2+7)^3\cdot4(t^3-7)^3\cdot3t^2$. Does this seem correct to you?

Comment: Yes, that looks correct.

Comment: $f(x)$ in your post is not correct. $f(t)$ is correct. so I tried to edit your post.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $p(x)=(8x^2+7)^3(x^3-7)^4$ then by the product rule $(fg)' = f'g + fg'$ we have $f(x) = (8x^2+7)^3$ and $g(x) = (x^3-7)^4$ so by the product and chain rule

$$p'(x) = 48x(8x^2+7)^2(x^3-7)^4 + 12x^2(8x^2+7)^3(x^3-7)^3\\=12x(8x^2+7)^2(x^3-7)^3(12x^3+7x-28).$$

Answer (score 0):

When you face problem like this one which only contains products, ratios and powers, your best friend is logarithmic differentiation $$f=(8x^2+7)^3(x^3-7)^4\implies \log(f)=3\log(8x^2+7)+4\log(x^3-7)$$ Differentiate both sides $$\frac{f'}f=3 \frac{16x}{8x^2+7}+4\frac{3x^2}{x^3-7}=\frac{12 x \left(12 x^3+7 x-28\right) }{(8x^2+7)(x^3-7)}$$ Now $$f'=f\times \frac{f'}f=(8x^2+7)^3(x^3-7)^4\frac{12 x \left(12 x^3+7 x-28\right) }{(8x^2+7)(x^3-7)}$$ $$f'=12 x \left(8 x^2+7\right)^2 \left(x^3-7\right)^3 \left(12 x^3+7 x-28\right)$$